# How to access the data from a table?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Table1:
[image: Table1]

Table2:
[image: Table2]

I am trying to scrape data from a table on a website.

There are two tables which have the same table class name, yet different ids.

I need to extract data from the table with ID "option".

```vb
Sub hsiotpions()
    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim i As Integer
    
    i = 1
    
    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    ieObj.Visible = False
    ieObj.navigate "https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI"
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    
    For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementById("option").getElementByTagName("tr")
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
            .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent
            .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
            .Range("E" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
            .Range("F" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(5).textContent
            .Range("G" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(6).textContent
            .Range("H" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(7).textContent
            .Range("I" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(8).textContent
            .Range("J" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(9).textContent
            .Range("K" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(10).textContent
            .Range("L" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(11).textContent
        End With
        
        i = i + 1
        
    Next htmlEle

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the id to select the table. Just be sure to handle columns 4 and 8 correctly for writing out to sheet.

In your code you have an error where you don't use the plural:

```
getElementByTagName("tr")
```

That should be

```
getElementsByTagName("tr")
```

Which returns a collection.

The rows for the table body actually have the same class name and I use those below to loop the rows.

I don't like hard coded wait times but as I can't currently see a good indicator for when page fully loaded you can adjust the following line until you get all the rows

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
```

The end argument is a wait time in seconds.

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ie As Object, table As Object, headers()
    Dim headersTop As Object, ele As Object

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    headers = Array("OI", "Volume", "IV", "Bid/Ask", "Last", "Strike", "Last", "Bid/Ask", "IV", "Volume", "OI")  '<== This is second row of headers

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)

        Set table = .document.querySelector("#option")
        Set headersTop = .document.querySelectorAll("#option tr:first-child th")  '<== This is top row of headers which involves merged table cells. I prepare the excel sheet in the same way in the code below.
        ws.Range("A1:D1").Merge
        ws.Range("A1").Value = headersTop.item(0).innerText  ' CALL
        ws.Range("E1:G1").Merge
        ws.Range("E1") = headersTop.item(1).innerText  '< Date
        ws.Range("H1:K1").Merge
        ws.Range("H1") = headersTop.item(2).innerText  '< PUT
        ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        Dim r As Long, c As Long, td As Object, tr As Object
        r = 3
        For Each tr In table.getElementsByClassName("tdrow") 'loop the rows below the headers by using class name to isolate
            c = 1
            For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td") '< loop table cells i.e. columns of rows
                ws.Cells(r, c) = IIf(c Mod 4 = 0, "'" & td.innerText, td.innerText)  '< If column number is 4 or 8 then add "'" in front so formatting preserved
            c = c + 1
            Next
            r = r + 1
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**CSS selectors:**

I am using [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) initially. Modern browsers are optimized for working with css (which govern page styling). We apply css selectors via [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) methods of, in this instance, `ie.document`.

Here is what `#option tr:first-child th`  is selecting:

[image]

You can see it is the top level headers. As there are actually more columns than this in the table we know we have merged cells.

As we want more than one header we use `querySelectorAll` method, as opposed to `querySelector` which returns a single element, to return a `nodeList` of matched elements as specified by the selector inside the (""). Items in the nodeList are then accessed by index starting from 0.

---

Table body:

I have retrieved the table of interest by id with

```
Set table = .document.querySelector("#option")
```

The # is a css id selector and is semantically equivalent to:

```
Set table = .document.getElementById("option")
```

Just, css selector method should prove faster except on very old IE versions.

When we have the table we know that rows are the `tr` elements and `td` are the table cells (columns).

Looking at the table rows in our `table` variable you see we have the two varying length headers:

[image]

This is why I chose not to loop these attempting to write out. The bottom row is static in values, so I put these in the array variable `headers` to write out. The top row has a dynamic value for date, so I use a css selector to retrieve that row by itself:

```
Set headersTop = .document.querySelectorAll("#option tr:first-child th")
```

and index into the returned nodeList to place the items in the various merged cells as dictated by one webpage layout.

But notice that the table body rows all have the same class name:

[image]

So, I select for these by using class name on the table rows with:

```
For Each tr In table.getElementsByClassName("tdrow")
```

Then I loop the columns within those rows with:

```
For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
```

Because columns 4 and 8 have a format Excel will try to handle as dates/fractions you want to add "'" in fron to preserve formatting:

[image]

```
ws.Cells(r, c) = IIf(c Mod 4 = 0, "'" & td.innerText, td.innerText)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Because I am new to using vba as one of my tools, your codes seem advanced to me. And I tried the code. It does return the first two rows; however remaining rows don't show up as expected.

Comment: I have added a hard coded wait time which I don't like but may be ok for now if you set it high enough. I have also added notes in the code.

Comment: thank you a lot for being such a mentor of vba to me. You have detailed the techniques deployed in fishing the code. By the way, is it possible to add a function ( enter the strike price range of options you look for, load the data and export the data to excel )  to the code?

Comment: This is the code I added for the above suggested function, but it didn't work. Can you have a look for me?

Dim obj As Object, startk As Long, endk As Long
startk = InputBox("Min strike price:")
endk = InputBox("Max strike price:")
.document.all.Item("mss_list val valstart").innerText = startk
.document.all.Item("mss_list val valend").innerText = endk
 Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
.document.getElementsByName("load").Item.Click

Comment: Hi, please ask a new question if you want to do a function. Show your attempt there and explain what isn't working. Also, do you really want to lauch IE each time you want to make a selection. Why not have a button click sub that gets lots of different selections in one go?

Comment: If I dont want IE to be launched every time I run the module, can I turn to false in .visible ? Also, I have published another question for the proposed function. Thank you for reminding.

Comment: What is the difference between not launching it and not seeing it in this case? Can you explain the possible action I can take to do so?

Comment: If you are using IE it will be launched. I am saying run a sub which launches IE once and loops the dates/options you are interested in and collects those and returns them all in one go to the sheet. As opposed to a function which would launch IE each time you made a selection. Unless you are only very rarely going to make selections a sub would be more efficient. Setting to = False simply means that user won't be aware that browser has launched.